# How to set TextFormFields and Controllers in dynamics Cards using Listview builder

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-card, flutter-textformfield

I am trying to build each Card with textformfields when the button is pressed, until it reaches some limit like 10 cards only, So when I pressed the floating button, Card is adding but text in textformfields is erasing for every press. Can anyone help me to build Cards dynamically with textformfields without erasing for every press? Below I am attaching screenshots of app.[image: 1st card][image: after pressing button text is erasing]

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: CardWithTextformfield(),
    );
  }
}

class CardWithTextformfield extends StatefulWidget {
  const CardWithTextformfield({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CardWithTextformfieldState createState() => _CardWithTextformfieldState();
}

class _CardWithTextformfieldState extends State<CardWithTextformfield> {

  var name =<TextEditingController>[];
  var id =<TextEditingController>[];

  var addCard =0;

  void incrementcard(){
    setState(() {
      if(addCard >=7){
        return;
      }
      addCard++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Card with TextformField'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: incrementcard,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child:ListView.builder(
          itemCount: addCard,
            itemBuilder: (context,index){
            return cardslist();
            }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget cardslist(){
    var nameController = TextEditingController();
    var idController = TextEditingController();
    name.add(nameController);
    id.add(idController);
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Text('Name: ')),
                Expanded(child: TextFormField(
                  controller: nameController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Name'),
                ),),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Text('EmpId: '),),
                Expanded(child: TextFormField(
                  controller: idController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'EmpId'),
                ),),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you re-create every controller when a new card is inserted, that's why the entered values are lost. Instead you should check for whether controllers already exist in your array for the current card, and if yes, use the existing controllers, otherwise create a new ones.

To do so, you have to add `index` as a parameter to your `cardsList` method. The code below I think will solve your problem.

**Important**: controllers should be destroyed when this widget is destroyed, please add that part. You should override `dispose` method in your `_CardWithTextformfieldState`, loop through all of your controllers in both arrays, and call `dispose()` on every controller. At the end do not forget to call `super.dispose()`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: CardWithTextformfield(),
    );
  }
}

class CardWithTextformfield extends StatefulWidget {
  const CardWithTextformfield({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CardWithTextformfieldState createState() => _CardWithTextformfieldState();
}

class _CardWithTextformfieldState extends State<CardWithTextformfield> {
  final _name = <TextEditingController>[];
  final _id = <TextEditingController>[];
  int _addCard = 0;

  void _incrementcard() {
    setState(() {
      if (_addCard >= 7) {
        return;
      }
      _addCard++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Card with TextformField'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementcard,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _addCard,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return cardslist(index);
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget cardslist(int index) {
    if (_name.length <= index) {
      _name.add(TextEditingController());
      _id.add(TextEditingController());
    }

    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(margin: EdgeInsets.all(10), child: Text('Name: ')),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _name[index],
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Name'),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Text('EmpId: '),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _id[index],
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'EmpId'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @peter-koltai Thanks for solving the problem, but I didn't understand what you saying on an important note, I'm just a beginner to flutter so can you help me to understand.

Comment: You are welcome. Please check the example [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes), it shows how to properly dispose a controller. You have to do the same with all of the controllers created.

Comment: Hey @peter-koltai can you help me to create a default one card at starting?

Comment: @shanmkha What help do you need exactly need?

Comment: I got the answer, I want to create a single card at starting of the screen, I just  used `@override 
void initState(){
super.initState();
incrementCard();
}`

Comment: You can simply use this: `int _addCard = 1;` instead of `int _addCard = 0;`. Avoid using `setState` in `initState`!

Comment: Hey @peter can you help me with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/68984838/16094734
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hai @Peter could you help me for my another question [New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69491598/how-to-customize-the-horizontal-time-picker-in-flutter)